# How to use static Dialog with buttons in Common Utils

Tags: android, static, dialog, onclicklistener, customdialog

I use custom dialog for some activities. I create showDialog method in CommonUtils and call from BaseActivity. But Choices' onClick methods have to set in viewmodel. I can't option's onClick method other class. How to use dialog options in CommonUtils?
CommonUtils:

```
public final class CommonUtils extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private CommonUtils() {
    }
public static boolean showDialog(Context context){
        final boolean[] result = new boolean[1];
        PrettyDialog prettyDialog = new PrettyDialog(context);
        prettyDialog.setMessage("Seçiminiz:");
        prettyDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.question_icon);
        prettyDialog.addButton("EVET", R.color.pdlg_color_white, R.color.pdlg_color_green, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                result[0] = true;
                prettyDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        prettyDialog.addButton("HAYIR", R.color.pdlg_color_white, R.color.pdlg_color_red, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                result[0] = false;
                prettyDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        prettyDialog.show();
        return result[0];
    }
}
```

Call method in BaseActivity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean getDialogResult() {
        return CommonUtils.showDialog(this);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DialogViewModel extends BaseViewModel<BaseNavigator> {
    @Inject
    public DialogViewModel(){

    }

    public void onDialogButtonClick(View view){
        boolean result= getNavigator().getDialogResult();
        if (result==true){
            getNavigator().hideLoading();
            getNavigator().showLoading();
        }

    }
    public boolean testDialogResult(){
       return getNavigator().getDialogResult();
    }
}
```

I try pull result value from commonutils. But "onDialogButtonClick" only use open dialog and doesn't use "yes" or "no" action. result value cant pull.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
Just add one listener to the dialog button click handling
i.e. like

```java
public interface ClickHandlerListener {
        /**
         * will work for positive(ok/yes) click
         */
        void onPositiveClick();

        /**
         * will work for negative(no/cancel) click
         */
        void onNegativeClick();
    }
```

Now set this listener to your dialog methods like

```java
public static boolean showDialog(Context context){
        final boolean[] result = new boolean[1];
        PrettyDialog prettyDialog = new PrettyDialog(context);
        prettyDialog.setMessage("Seçiminiz:");
        prettyDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.question_icon);
        prettyDialog.addButton("EVET", R.color.pdlg_color_white, R.color.pdlg_color_green, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                        if (clickHandler != null) clickHandler.onPositiveClick();

                result[0] = true;
                prettyDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        prettyDialog.addButton("HAYIR", R.color.pdlg_color_white, R.color.pdlg_color_red, new PrettyDialogCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                        if (clickHandler != null) clickHandler.onNegativeClick();

                result[0] = false;
                prettyDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        prettyDialog.show();
        return result[0];
    }
}
```

And create on method to set call back for the dialog to the acitivity or fragmrnt which call the dialog

```java
public void setDialogClick(ClickHandlerListener click) {
        clickHandler = click;
    }
```

Now call to set the listener callback to the activity/fragment i.e.

```java
setdialogClick(this);
```

and make sure your activity or fragment implemented the listener to pass this in method else you can also implement listener methods anonymously.

Comment: thank you but this answer doesn't solve. error: non-static field 'clickHandler' cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: If you want for static method please change the syntax of method to
```
showDialog (Context context,ClickHandlerListener handler)
```
And after that, we don't need the setDialogClick method to initialize handler reference.

Comment: Is that helpful for you?

Comment: No :( I call method showDialog(this,ClickHandler) error click handler object and I cant  use listener

Comment: How can I use onPositiveClick on Acitiviy